# How to specialize a class template for an integral type with the integral type itself?

Tags: c++11, templates, template-specialization

I have a class template `X` which looks as follows:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class X {
 public:
   X(T &t): t_ {t} {}

 private:
   T &t_;
};
```

Is there a way to specialize it for `T = int` such that an expression `X<int>(i)` for an integer `i` does nothing but "returns" just `i` compile time?

In other words, I would like to have the same syntax for `double` and `int` (`X<double>(d)` and `X<int>(i)` respectively) but the former calls a constructor that initializes a reference as showed in the code above, while the latter ignores that "syntax sugar" and "returns" integer `i` without doing anything.

Comment: So you want something like `int n = X<int>(i);` to work?

Comment: From the spec "[temp] A template defines a family of classes or functions or an alias for a family of types." and "[temp.decls] 3. Because an alias-declaration cannot declare a template-id, it is not possible to partially or explicitly specialize
an alias template." so there is no specialization for what you are asking. However DeiDei points out an alternative approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could supply a template specialization for `int` and `double` respectively and use a conversion operator. Something like this:

```
// the same applies for double
template<>
class X<int> {
 public:
   constexpr X(int t) : t_ {t} {}

   constexpr operator int() const { return t; }

 private:
   int t_;
};
```

That will allow something like the following to work (correct me if I misunderstood your question):

```
constexpr int n = X<int>(20); // n == 20
```

Comment: Dear @DeiDei, you understood my question correctly. What type would `n` have if we define it as `constexpr auto n = X<int>(20)`. It is `X<int>`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It's converted to an `int` only when an `int` is required. But I believe this is the closest you could get to what you want.

Comment: I'll definitely accept your answer. Thanks for such a prompt response.